# Excel - Pivot Chart - Count if a Start Time and End Time fall into timeslot

Tags: excel, pivot-table, calculated-field, slicers, pivot-chart

I'll do my best to explain.

I have data which has the Start Time and Period of Time an activity is carried out for.
e.g.

```
Name   Start Time  Activity Length (mins)
James    08:00           45
Phil     10:10           30
Angela   10:20           50
```

I want to display a graph with Time on the `x-axis` and a count on the `y-axis` for every time an activity is in progress during that time period.

I'd like to have this in a `PivotTable` as the data will change often (currently saved as an Excel Table `Table1`), and it'll interact with slicers connected to other graphs. I've shown below what I would expect the `PivotTable` to look like based on the data above (not including James).

e.g.

```
Time   Count
10:00  0
10:05  0
10:10  1
10:15  1
10:20  2
10:25  2
10:30  2
10:35  2
10:40  2
10:45  1
10:50  1
10:55  1
11:00  1
11:05  1
11:10  0
11:15  0
11:20  0
```

This is simple enough without Pivot Tables using a `countif` :

```
=countifs(StartTime,"<="&A1,StartTime+(ActivityLength/1440),"<"&A1),
```

but looks like I would need a Pivot if the data is constantly changing and several filters need applying.
By the way, I'm using Excel 2010

Comment: You could probably do this if you installed the free PowerPivot addin from Microsoft, and wrote some measures against the DataModel. Otherwise I'm thinking that you need VBA to generate the second table from the first, so that it can then be pivoted as you require.

Comment: Thanks, I've breifly looked at PowerPivot. Sadly it's a work project and once finished it would be used by different users on separate computers that wouldn't have the PowerPivot add-in.